# Send bulk commands from a file to firewall using a script

Tags: linux, bash, expect, send

Below is my script which has commands in command.txt and using spawn for doing ssh to firewall, its failing to execute echo command to input firewall name, do not understand what is wrong.

```
!/bin/bash

expect <<'END'

# Set variables

set username $env(USER)
set password [lindex $argv 1]

echo 'Please enter FQDN/IP address of the FW'

read -p 'Firewall FQDN/IP: ' hostname

# Announce which device we are working on and at what time
send_user "\n"
send_user ">>>>>  Working on $hostname @ [exec date] <<<<<\n"
send_user "\n"

# Don't check keys
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username\@$hostname

# send bulk commands to hostname from a file commands.txt
for commands in `cat $commands.txt`; do
    send "$commands";
done
send -- "exit\n"

END
```

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` and `read` are shell commands, but you have them in the expect code. Your `for` loop has the same problem.

Instead of mixing shell and expect code, you can simply use expect for the whole task: I'm also getting the user to type the password instead of providing it on the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set username $env(USER)

# read the hostname from the user
send_user "Enter the hostname: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set hostname $expect_out(1,string)

# read the password from the user, without echoing to the screen
stty -echo
send_user -- "Password for $username@$hostname: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
set password $expect_out(1,string)

# Announce which device we are working on and at what time
send_user "\n"
send_user ">>>>>  Working on $hostname @ [timestamp -format "%a %b %d %Y, %T"] <<<<<\n"
send_user "\n"

# Don't check keys
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$hostname

expect {
    "assword:" {send -- "$password\r"}
    timeout    {error "Did not see password prompt in $timeout seconds"}
}

set fh [open commands.txt r]
while {[gets $fh command] != -1} {
    # Here, waiting for your prompt. 
    # If it does not end with dollar and space, change this pattern
    expect -re {\$ $}           
    send "$command\r";
}
close $fh

expect -re {\$ $}           
send -- "exit\n"
expect eof
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glenn, I will check this and come back if any issues .

Comment: I tested with minor adjstments according to the firewall output , It works !! Thanks again!